# How to make first element of menu active

Tags: wordpress

Right now my menu getting active if i click on some menu item, but when site just gets loaded it doesn't have active menu so i want to make first li as active.

This code makes active menu by adding current-menu-item

```
    add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

    function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
        if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
            $classes[] = 'active';
        } 
        return $classes;
    }

function main_menu() {
    add_theme_support('menus');
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'primary' => __('Primary Main Menu'),
    ));
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'secondary' => __('Primary Portfolio Navigation'),
    ));
}

$args = array(
    'container' => '',
    'menu_id' => false,
    'items-wrap' => '%3$s',
    'theme_location' => 'primary'
);

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for that filter code, just do as following:

1- register a menu in functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
           'top-menu' => 'Top Menu'
        )
    );
}
```

2- Then in your code where you wanted to be just put this following code:

```
<ul>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'top-menu','container'=>'', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s')); ?>
</ul>
```

3- Finally go to admin panel, Appearance->Menus, select `Top Menu` and fill it with your pages, this should handle all the `active` html classes, there is no need to do it manually.

Comment: i alreayd did that,b ut itš not working, please check i updated my code

Comment: @Andrew you should register you menu directly inside functions.php NOT INSIDE another function like `main_menu`

Comment: this doesn't changed anything

Comment: @Andrew also wrap it with <ul></ul>, like `<ul><?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?></ul>`, and `items_wrap` not `items-wrap` in $args

Comment: wp_nav_menu is wrapped in ul and changed to underscore but still the same(

Comment: @Andrew also comment the `filter` lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152047/discussion-between-aliawwad-and-andrew).